# this.$refs.selectedImages.files.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, windows, vue.js, electron

I'm working on an vue-electron app. I have some problem with the windows build. It seems that when the user select some files and I try to get them using `$refs` this will not work. I have a simple file input like this

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" ref="selectedImages" @change="handleFiles()">
```

In my vue component code I've added a method called `handleFiles()` it will only get the files path and the type for each file that is in the file object

```
this.$refs.selectedImages.files.forEach( (file) => {
 const fileDetails = {path: file.path, type: file.type}
 this.files.push(fileDetails);
});
```

The code works fine on macOS and no error occur, the files are selected and are correctly iterated from the loop. The issue will happen only in windows build where seems that the file input isn't selected using `$refs`. Is there any solution to solve this problem? I'm thinking to replace the `$refs` with a `for` loop but not sure about.

**EDIT**

I've switched from `forEach()` loop to a `for()`. Now the error seems solved but I've noticed an issue with the file path when they are passed to the main process. In my virtualbox win10 test machine, I've found into the console that the files path are wrong

if the file path is `C:\Users\debug\Desktop\filename.jpg` it will be passed with an extra slash char `C:\\Users\\debug\\Desktop\\filename.jpg`. Is possible to fix?

Answer (score 2):

FileList is not an array. Try to transform it into the array:

```
Array.from(this.$refs.selectedImages.files).forEach( (file) => {
 const fileDetails = {path: file.path, type: file.type}
 this.files.push(fileDetails);
});
```